# Bootstrap 3 menu dropdown strange BUG

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a site usng bootstrap 3. Now the problem is with navbar dropdown.
When i click the link it gets changed into **expand child menu** and **collapse child menu**

to clearify here is the pic i am trying to tell
at first
[image]

THen when i click it becomes

[image]

Finally again [image]

Where did my gallery menu text go to ???
Hope some one can help.

Comment: Can you add your `navbar` code?

Comment: should show some code here.

Comment: show your navbar code..

Comment: solved it just now. It was because of the wordpress screen reader text js code which was conflicting with bootstraps code.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this problem in Wordpress, I fixed this by commenting out a couple of lines in my theme's functions.php file.

Find the line

```
wp_localize_script('themeName-script', 'screenReaderText', array('expand' => ..., 'collapse' => ...);
```

And comment out the 'expand' and 'collapse' array items. I'm guessing this could have unintended consequences in other parts of your app if you actually need to use screenReaderText somewhere else, however I don't so this worked perfectly.